# Real time voice transcription using Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io, transcription, videocall

I have problem with real-time voice transcription. In my application people can make a video call each other according to their language choice, I want to show subtitles of conversations in real time to users. I used Agora SDK for video call feature. Is it possible to add real-time transcription?

I found **Google Cloud Speech API** but there is not enough documentation for dart. I would really be pleased if you give me some starting point

Answer (score 1):

It is just a suggestion. I don’t know if it is valid or not, but you can try. You can apply the Java code or Kotlin or Xamarin, this will help you in setting 'Google Cloud Speech API'.
Excuse me for my explanation, I hope to be of benefit to you

Comment: thank you for your suggestion , I am trying something right now. If I can figure out then I will add here

Comment: I hope you successful